# Turn link to a jQuery icon

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, icons, hyperlink

I want to turn two "voting" links into jQuery UI icons. One is the upvote link that should be an icon with an up arrow, and one is the downvote link that should be an icon with a down arrow. Here is one of the link's RoR code:

```
<%= link_to "+1", video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :method => :post, :remote => true %>
```

I also want to change the color of the icon when it is clicked, and when it is clicked again, it should change back to its original color. How can I do all of this?

Comment: You're asking for a jQuery **button** containing an icon, not a *jQuery icon*. Are you using jQuery UI elsewhere in your application as well? What you're asking for is very easily achieved with some CSS and a JS one-liner, jQuery UI might be a bit overkill if you need the button functionality otherwise and especially if you are not using jQuery UI otherwise.

Comment: I'm not using it elsewhere... I'd definitely accept a CSS and JS example for an answer. It doesn't need to be jQuery UI.

Comment: Please see my suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

A solution only using CSS and touch of JS via jQuery:

Create a sprite of your icon, the two versions of your arrow (one for each color) beneath each other — e.g. something like this:

[image]

Give your links classes `vote` and add a bit of CSS and jQuery magic.

**CSS:**

```
// will show the upper part of the sprite by default
a.vote {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -999em;
  width: 15px;             // width of your sprite
  height: 15px;            // half the height of your sprite
  background: transparent url(your_sprite.png) no-repeat center top;
}

// will show the lower part of the sprite when toggled
a.vote.selected {
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('a.vote').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you create your own sprite? And how would you get the sprite arrows inside a button?

Comment: You will need some image editing software like Photoshop e.g. or try to find a ready sprite online. Are you referring to a `<button>` HTML element?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could either make it a button with the sprite image inside, or the sprite image could be of a button.

Comment: Not sure if I'm following you. The sprite will only work as CSS background image (or you need to implement some sort of masking). If you don't want to use a sprite, you can also use two separate BG images, one for each state. But be aware that the second one will need to load before showing up, which might cause a flickering when clicking the button for the first time.

Comment: hmm, the thing is that I don't have photoshop, and I have no idea how to create these sprites...

Comment: You can use any image software (Gimp e.g.?). This is a very basic task. If you don't feel like doing that in any case, grab two images from the web (e.g. jQuery UI icons and not only change the `background-position` on `hover` but the whole image. But since this is one of the fundamental techniques used online, I'd recommend to try it out and preferably create your own images.